# Roles.GetRolesForUser() is empty

Tags: vb.net

I have never worked on authorization in Vb.Net before. So the below question might sound stupid for advanced programmers. Please apologize.

I am trying to get the list of the Active Directory Groups of the logged in user. I was told that Roles.GetRolesForUser() is the best way to achieve it. I wrote the below code in my web.config.

```
<roleManager
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="true" >
</roleManager>
```

and added the below code in code behind.

```
Dim userRoles As String() = Roles.GetRolesForUser()
```

I see the userRoles.length is 0. I verified the user is having more than one active directory groups associated with. Either this is because the configuration which I set in web.config is wrong or this is not the way to get all the active directory groups for this user. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Has the use actually logged in? (Until they do they're just another anonymous surfer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either I am too stupid to understand the Roles.GetRolesForUser() or configuring it is really hard.:)

I solved this problem using `IsInRole()` method. I knew the possible ADGroups which would access my app and made that as a configurable item in web.config. Then used `String.Split()` and then manually checked with `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole()` to verify the user can access the app.